EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor manual invalidation
I have tried to ask this question from the library's author, but he assumed something that was not true for my scenario, afterwards he closed the thread without letting me explain what my question actually is. Rude IMHO...
The question is related to this part: https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor?tab=readme-ov-file#3--setting-up-the-cache-invalidation
I have a service that sometimes (rarely) changes data. I have other services that read the same data in a read-only manner and do their own caching in memory for the whole DbContext. They keep the data in the cache as long as possible (sliding). But in the rare cases when the data is changed, I need to invalidate that in those read-only services. Manually, since the writing and reading contexts are not only not the same, but on different hosts, hence the auto-invalidation won't work evidently. Signaling the fact of the data change from that one service to the read-only ones is set up, some latency is also not an issue. But currently, I can only invalidate the whole cache at once.
The interceptor has some mechanism for manual invalidation. But the description is vague. It's not even clear if what I want is possible at all.
I need to invalidate only entries that relate to specific table(s).

You probably need to provide minimum reproducible example, since it’s absolutely not obvious what you are trying to achieve.

Are you familiar with this specific library?

Btw how the heck do you want me to reproduce two services with shared database and rabbitmq HERE???

Based on the result of some digging and debugging, it seems, that the InvalidateCacheDependencies method does exactly what I need, although has some caveats: the internal storage keeps track of the tables used in the cached query by adding that prefix for some reason, but without adding the schema. Meaning that having the same table name in more schemas might present an issue here. If any of the prefixed table names passed to the method was found to be related to a cached query, the entry is invalidated. Meaning that no fine-grained invalidation is possible.
